Laravel reactphp/socket how to target connections
This is inside a laravel 11 project using reactphp/socket TcpServer.
how do you target a specific connection?

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use React\EventLoop\Loop;
use React\Socket\ConnectionInterface;
use React\Socket\TcpServer;

class SocketTest extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'socket:test';
    protected $description = 'Run asynchronous socket server';
    public function handle()
    {
        $loop = Loop::get();
        $socket = new TcpServer('0.0.0.0:8001', $loop);
        $socket->on('connection', function (ConnectionInterface $connection) {
            echo "connected\n";
            $connection->on('data', function ($data) use ($connection) {
                $connection->write('You are connected!');
                echo $data . "\n";
            });
            $connection->on('end', function () use ($connection) {
                echo $connection->getRemoteAddress() . " Ended \n";
            });
            $connection->on('close', function () use ($connection) {
                echo $connection->getRemoteAddress() . " Closed \n";
            });
            $connection->on('error', function (\Exception $exception) use ($connection) {
                echo $connection->getRemoteAddress() . " Error \n";
                var_dump($exception);
            });
        });
        $loop->run();
    }
}

what i'm hoping for is a connection id or something similar but i can't seem to find it.
what i want to achieve is to write to the connection from an api controller
Edit
I did ab it of research and found people saving connections to a global scope as they connect and using them that way; if there is no alternative solution i'll go with this.
